# Find the minimum size of the largest clique in a graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I was trying to solve a problem on finding the minimum size of the largest clique in a graph and came across the following statement of Turan's theorem.
A graph with `m(k-1)` vertices and `(k-1)C2*m^2+1` edges contains a clique of size `k`.
Using the above concept, I developed two equations; given the number of edges and vertices.
Finally, I got
[image]

where k is the size of the clique. My code is as follows:

```
double n,m; cin>>n>>m;
    cout<<round((2*m-2-2*n*n)/(2*m-2-n*n))<<endl;
```

I submitted my code,but it failed some of the test cases. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: what test cases it failed?

Comment: It is a very large list. You can submit the code at https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/clique and see the test cases.

Comment: 1) You didn't check if you're dividing by 0.  2) Using formulas from a math book many times do not translate well to computers due to computers using binary, not decimal, thus your answers could differ by a small amount from whatever the answers are for hackerrank.  This is where you need the test case that fails, and see for yourself what the issue is.

Comment: Constraints: `2 <= N <= 10000` and `1 <= M <= N*(N-1)/2` what if m = 3 and n = 2?

Comment: m=3 and n=2 violates the second constraint. The range for m

Comment: You should for the very least check if k is the lower integer part of the right hand side, or the upper integer part. Also -- I believe -- Turan's theorem *guarantees* you the existence of a clique of size k, but it does not tell you how big a clique can actually be.

Comment: So @Matsmath, this means that my code gives the minimum size of a clique in a graph. That is, the minimum size of clique a particular graph can have; not the maximum. Right?